# How do I get both of my arrays to be read in?

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

I have two arrays the store the values of two lines that are read in from a file. After some processing in my GUI class it should show to rectangles side by side in the middle of the frame. However only one ever shows up. I have tried every way I know how to get the other one to show up but no dice. Here is my code:

```
public class PortraitFileReader 

    public static ArrayList<Drawable> readFile(File a) {
    File myFile;
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Drawable> couple = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    Man aMan;
    Woman aWoman;
    Point aPoint;
    String input;
    String [] array = null;
    String [] array2 = null;
    try {
        myFile = a;
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(myFile);
        input = inFile.nextLine();
        array = input.split(", ");

        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            input = inFile.nextLine();
            array2 = input.split(", ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));        
        }

        if(array[0].equals("man")) {
            for(int i=1; i<array.length-1; i++) {
                    int current = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
                    values.add(current);
                    System.out.println(values);
                }
                aPoint = new Point(values.get(0), values.get(1));
                aMan = new Man(aPoint, values.get(2), values.get(3), array[5]);
                couple.add(aMan);
                values.clear();


        }

        if(array[0].equals("woman")) {
            for(int i=1; i<array.length-1; i++) {
                int current = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
                values.add(current);
                System.out.println(values);
            }
            aPoint = new Point(values.get(0), values.get(1));
            aWoman = new Woman(aPoint, values.get(2), values.get(3), array[5]);
            couple.add(aWoman);
            values.clear();
        }

        if(array2[0].equals("man")) {
            for(int i=1; i<array2.length-1; i++) {
                int current = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
                values.add(current);
                System.out.println(values);
            }
            aPoint = new Point(values.get(0), values.get(1));
            aMan = new Man(aPoint, values.get(2), values.get(3), array2[5]);
            couple.add(aMan);
            values.clear();
        }

        if(array2[0].equals("woman")) {
            for(int i=1; i<array2.length-1; i++) {
                    int current = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
                    values.add(current);
                    System.out.println(values);
                }
            aPoint = new Point(values.get(0), values.get(1));
            aWoman = new Woman(aPoint, values.get(2), values.get(3), array2[5]);
            couple.add(aWoman);
            values.clear();
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file was not found.");
    }
    return couple;
}
}
```

This is the data that I'm reading in from the file:

```
man, 260, 100, 40, 80, Tom  
woman, 300, 100, 40, 80, Sally
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: the system.out.println's are just there to test if each array had the right values in it.

Comment: Wow, there's an awful lot of code repetition there.

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm just trying to get it working first and I spread it all out to see to try and make the problem easier to see.

Comment: So the two arrays have the correct contents but one is not showing on the screen? Or the array contents are not correct?

Comment: I commented out all of the other value printlns and left in the one for woman in array2 and it still prints out the man's values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are going through array2 checking if it is a woman, you are actually going through the variable array.

```
 for(int i=1; i<***array2***.length-1; i++) {
int current = Integer.parseInt(****array***[i]);
```

The same goes for when you are checking if array2 is a man

The effect of this is that you are processing the contents of the first line twice.

Comment: Your code duplication "to make the problem easier to see" was the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Um, I can barely read it, so I rewrote it:

```
public class PortraitFileReader {

public static ArrayList<Drawable> readFile(File file) {
    ArrayList<Drawable> couple = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            couple.add(parseLine(scanner.nextLine()));
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file was not found.");
    }
    return couple;
}

public static Drawable parseLine(String line) {
    String [] array = line.split(", ");
    String gender = array[0];
    int pointX = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    int pointY = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
    int width  = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
    int height = Integer.parseInt(array[4]);
    String name = array[5];
    if(gender.equals("man")) {
        return new Man(new Point(pointX, pointY), width, height, name);
    } else {
        return new Woman(new Point(pointX, pointY), width, height, name);
    }
}

}
```

Anyway, it looks like either you're not drawing your drawable right, or the input in the file isn't exactly formatted as you expect. The parsing itself seems to make sense....
except that you're always parsing `array`, and not switching it to `parseInt(array2[i])` in the 3rd and 4th block. Which just demonstrates why collapsing these cut and pasted blocks into one method is the sensible way to go.

Inlining everything would look like the above with these edits:

```
....
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            Drawable person = null;
            // everything from parseLine, change return to assignment to person
            couple.add(person);
        }
....
```

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but in the specs I was given this class is only supposed to contain one static method. Which makes code duplication hard to not do.

Comment: That seems really unusual. Can the static method create an instance of `PortraitFileReader` and call non-static methods on it? Either way, you can inline the `parseLine` method into the `while` loop.